# Check if value is in array - DatePicker Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uidatepicker

I need to check if the hour selected by the user is outside of working hours. 
I am trying to achieve this result with a `for in loop` and `switch` statement, but I am not sure how to implement this. 
If `var components` matches a value in the `timeRestricted` array, it should break from the switch statement. Thanks for your help.

```
class FourthViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var myDatePicker: UIDatePicker!
                var currentTime = NSDate()
                let timeRestricted = [00,01,02,03,04,05,06,19,20,21,22,23]
                var dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
var dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

@IBOutlet weak var someLabel: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm"

    // load current time as minimum date
    self.myDatePicker.minimumDate = NSDate(timeInterval: 1, sinceDate: currentTime)

    myDatePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.datePickerAction(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)


}


func datePickerAction(sender: UIDatePicker) {

    var timeSelected = sender.date
    var unitFlags: NSCalendarUnit = [.Hour]
    var components = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(unitFlags, fromDate: timeSelected)



    for components in timeRestricted {
        switch components {
        case timeRestricted[0...12]: print("update label")

        default: print(" record input data and segue to next screen")
        }



     }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several misunderstandings in your code.

First, you have an `NSDateComponent` in your local variable `components`. Using `for components in timeRestricted {...}` introduces another local variable `components`, which would not be what you intend.

Second, you cannot use array as a `case` label. So, both `for-in` and `switch-case` does not fit for checking if an `hour` is included in the `timeRestricted`.

Maybe your `datePickerAction` needs to be something like this:

```
func datePickerAction(sender: UIDatePicker) {

    let timeSelected = sender.date
    let unitFlags: NSCalendarUnit = [.Hour]
    let components = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(unitFlags, fromDate: timeSelected)
    let hour = components.hour

    if timeRestricted.contains(hour) {
        print("update label")
    } else {
        print(" record input data and segue to next screen")
    }
}
```

---

Ok, let's see some other ways. One important thing in this case is that you need to retrieve `hour` value from the date `components`, so, the following codes replace the last 5 lines of my `datePickerAction(_:)` above.

Start with using `for-in`.

```
    var isInArray = false
    for restrictedHour in timeRestricted {
        if hour == restrictedHour {
            isInArray = true
            //We have no need to check the rest...
            break
        }
    }
    if isInArray {
        print("update label")
    } else {
        print(" record input data and segue to next screen")
    }
```

This code is very similar to what `contains(_:)` method does internally.
And, you know, the `for-in` syntax introduces a new variable. You'd better avoid using the same name as any of the existing variables. Which makes many readers of your code confused, including yourself.

---

To use `switch-case`, you need to write all comma-separated values directly after the `case` keyword.

```
    switch hour {
    case 00,01,02,03,04,05,06,19,20,21,22,23:
        print("update label")
    default:
        print(" record input data and segue to next screen")
    }
```

---

The two above were some examples using basic Swift control statements. But the last example is a little bit advanced.

Define an overload for `~=` operator (read as "matches"), somewhere at the top level (meaning outside of any `class` definitions nor such).

```
func ~= <T: Equatable>(lhs: [T], rhs: T) -> Bool {
    return lhs.contains(rhs)
}
```

Having this definition somewhere in your project, you can use array variables or constants for `case` label of `switch` statement.

```
    switch hour {
    case timeRestricted:
        print("update label")
    default:
        print(" record input data and segue to next screen")
    }
```

In this case, Swift uses that `~=` operator, so, this is nearly the same as the first example using `contains`. So confusing that I wouldn't recommend.

---

With just knowing you can retrieve `hour` as an `Int`, and some basics about Swift language, you have got so many ways to do the same thing. Do it as you like.

Comment: It works. If you were to implement same functionality with a for in and switch statement, how would you do it? Thanks

Comment: I have no time as for now, will update my answer later.